# How to test app after unpublishing it on play store

Tags: android, google-play, production

I tested my app in alpha and sent a few people the link to download and test it.
I then promoted the alpha version to production. that worked fine and more people downloaded, but then a few people experienced a pretty bad bug, where the app would turn it self without the user asking it to. So I decided to unpublish the app.
My question is:
How do I send a new testing version to the existing users only or people i send a testing link too ?